# How to capture artillery?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

I autoresolved a battle against a rebellion and got a shiny new mortar.
After several manual tries on the same battle, I have been unable to actually capture any artillery myself.

How does that work? What do you have to do?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is as follows -

- The army you are fighting against must be of the same faction
- The artillery crew must be wiped out and there artillery pieces intact
- You must have a spare unit slot at the end of the battle

Many people have stated that there is an element of randomness too. Some have quoted roughly a 10% chance to capture and this is decided before the battle so replaying the same battle over and over will likely end in the same result.

Comment: That must be it, probably a random element. But would like it confirmed.

Comment: Yes, it is random, but you need what DMK said, with that 3 points and a little bit of lucky, that arty is yours.

Answer (score 0):

After several manual battles i only get one capture art. I send one unit to attack them , forget that unit and battle finish while my unit was close, attacking the abandoned machines.
But others battles didnt work